# Twitter widget shows only 1 tweet on page load and can't lower the interval

Tags: twitter

When you add the [Twitter Search Widget](https://twitter.com/about/resources/widgets/widget_search) to your website, you see that the widget starts with only 1 tweet right after the page is loaded.

Is it possible to get the widget populated with more tweets on pageload?

It also seems that the interval can't be lowered due it's `'30000'` microseconds minimum. I tried to lower the interval in the code but it doesn't work. Is it possible to create a workaround for that?

```
<script charset="utf-8" src="http://widgets.twimg.com/j/2/widget.js"></script>
<script>
    new TWTR.Widget({
        version: 2,
        type: 'search',
        search: '#myhash',
        interval: 5000,
        title: '',
        subject: '',
        width: 'auto',
        height: 294,
        theme: {
            shell: {
                background: '#ffffff',
                color: '#000000'
            },
            tweets: {
                background: '#ffffff',
                color: '#444444',
                links: '#1985b5'
            }
        },
        features: {
            scrollbar: false,
            loop: true,
            live: true,
            behavior: 'default'
        }
    }).render().start();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <script>
        new TWTR.Widget({
          version: 2,
          type: 'profile',
          rpp: 3,
          interval: 30000,
          width: 240,
          height: 300,
            features: {
            hashtags: false,
            timestamp: false,
            avatars: false,
            scrollbar: false,
            loop: false,
            live: false,
            behavior: 'all'
          }
        }).render().setUser('USERNAME&exclude_replies=true').start();
     </script>
```

**rpp** being the number of tweets to show: Change the number to what ever you like. Also - I added &exclude_replies=true to turn off replies in my feed.